# Vector field interpolation

Tags: vector-spaces, interpolation, vector-fields

Given a discrete set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, there seem to be algorithms (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77701/interpolate-a-discrete-vector-field) that can 'interpolate' these vectors and give a smooth vector field on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that matches with the original vectors at their points. How exactly does this work?

Comment: The same as interpolating two scalar fields (one for each component)

Comment: So basically inverse distance interpolation to each component?

Comment: I don't know, there could be different interpolation methods. Are you asking how Mathematica does it?

Comment: Yeah, that is not how vector interpolation works. You don't just interpolate each component, it is more complicated than that.

Comment: So you do know how vector interpolation works? Then what is your question?